# How to stay at the same place of the page after you send post comment using Django-comments

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-comments

Now I use next code `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />` in comments/form.html and after I post a new comment the page with content and comments list refreshes and I should scroll down to see my post. It's not what I exactly want.

I want to stay at the same page after send a post, without refreshing. It's possible?

Comment: https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two principle ways of doing what you want:

1. Give a unique `id` for each comment and pass it to the url to create a so-called bookmark. You'll get smth like `http://the/url/you/want#desired-post-id` and so you will automatically jump to the post you want.
2. Use `ajax` to refresh only a part of a page that you are really changing. In that case you'll just stay there you are.